# Аналог UniformGrid для windows universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Существует ли аналог `UniformGrid` для windows universal apps?
У меня есть массив массивов вида `List<List<string>> = {{a},{b,c},{d,e},{f,g,h}}` и мне надо разместить его так, чтобы каждый элемент был отдельной строкой, а каждый подэлемент был отдельной, скажем, кнопкой. И каждый подэлемент должен быть растянут, если в элементе один подэлемент, он растянут на всю длину страницы, если элемента 3 - то каждый равномерно занимает треть страницы. Я нашел как это можно сделать в WPF с помощью `UniformGrid`, но я работаю под UWP и там `UniformGrid` нет. Поэтому и ищу его аналог, пробую написать свой класс `UniformGrid`. Но, может, такой аналог уже есть или есть альтернативный способ. Выглядеть должно примерно так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет. подобного элемента нет. выход - писать свою реализацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да,  Andrii Krupka, все верно. Воспользовался в итоге [данной](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html) статьей.